# Values argument to click function into modal button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am trying to pass a value to a function shooted when a modal button is pressed. The model is associated to a point on a map. The idea is to allow to erase the point from a dB clicking on the modal button opened.

My modal code is:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalTitle">TITLE</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cierra</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-eliminar" data-customer-id="myModalTitle" onclick="myCall()">Erase Point</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modal shows a TITLE and a photo. The last button shoots an ajax function:

```
function myCall() {
                    var self = $(this);
                    console.log(self.data("customer-id"));
                    alert('You clicked ' + self.data("customer-id")); 
                    var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        type: "GET",            
                        dataType: "html"
                    });

                    request.done(function(msg) {
                        $("#mybox").html(msg);
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');

                    });

                    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');

                    });
                }
```

I whant to to pass a customer-id (in this case the title) to the ajax php. But console web give me "undefined".

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the element as an object to your function by this in your html like

```
<button type="button" 
     class="btn btn-danger" 
     id="btn-eliminar" 
     data-customer-id="myModalTitle" 
     onclick="myCall(this)">
    Erase Point
</button>
```

and in functions

```
function myCall(self) { //self will hold HTML object your button
   self = $(self); //converting that object to jQuery object
   ...
```

The point is this inside the function is referring to the function inner scope not the button that you clicked, rest all is good

#### Edit 2: Added snippet

```js
function myCall(self) {
  self = $(self);
  console.log(self.data("customer-id"));
  alert('You clicked ' + self.data("customer-id")); 
  
  alert($('#myModal #'+self.data("customer-id")).text());
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "GET",            
    dataType: "html"
  });

  request.done(function(msg) {
    $("#mybox").html(msg);
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');

  });

  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');

  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalTitle">TITLE</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="" id="imagepreview" style="width: 400px; height: 264px;" >
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cierra</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-eliminar" data-customer-id="myModalTitle" onclick="myCall(this)">Erase Point</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tx. this solve the "undefined", but the parameter passed is the string "myModalTitle". I need the title asociated to that point

Comment: I need a point identifier inside mycall funcion. For ejmplo the modal title, defined into         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalTitle">TITLE</h4>

Comment: Are you looking for this. `$('#myModal #'+self.data("customer-id")).text()` check in the updated snippet

Comment: Tx! so I can pass the valiable $('#myModal #'+self.data("customer-id")).text()  to the ajax PHP Get function

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing "this" to your function. You can change it like:

```
onclick="myCall(this)"
```

You need to accept this in your function.

```
function myCall(self){
   self = $(self);
```

Alternatively, instead of the onclick tag, you can use this in jQuery:

```
$('#btn-eliminar').click(myCall);
```